# Display NV21 image using ImageMagick

Tags: android, imagemagick

In my Android project, I dump camera image as binary data to a file. The image size is 640x480 and the format is NV21.

I am trying to display this image using ImageMagick `display` utility:

```
$ display -size 640x480 -depth 8 -sampling-factor 4:2:2  Image.yuv
```

This results in displaying the image in four quarters. All the four quarters seem to show the same image. The first two images are discernible but in gray color. The other two images are barely discernible.

Perhaps this is happening because NV21 format (also called Y'UV420sp) is semi-planar. I am wondering if there is another option I need to specify to get the image displayed correctly.

Comment: Can you provide (a link to) a sample \*.yuv file?

Comment: Sure. Please try https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6i2Wq9ngUQKaGwtX1c0QXhsS3M/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the expected result, but you should try this command:

```
display                  \
  -size 640x480          \
  -depth 8               \
  -sampling-factor 4:2:0 \
  -colorspace srgb       \
   Image0.yuv
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Actually it was the `-sampling-factor 4:2:0` that did the trick!